# JS how to get month, week, past 3 days from today

Tags: javascript

In js how can I get the timestamp of a date like 2 weeks ago. For example I get the current timestamp, Then I need to get the timestamp 3 days ago, or 2 weeks ago, or a month ago. Is there a moment library that does this? I cant find anything online.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, check out Moment JS: https://momentjs.com/

```
moment().subtract(10, 'days').calendar(); // 02/11/2021
moment().subtract(6, 'days').calendar();  // Last Monday at 12:17 AM
moment().subtract(3, 'days').calendar();  // Last Thursday at 12:17 AM
moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar();  // Yesterday at 12:17 AM
moment().calendar();                      // Today at 12:17 AM
moment().add(1, 'days').calendar();       // Tomorrow at 12:17 AM
moment().add(3, 'days').calendar();       // Wednesday at 12:17 AM
moment().add(10, 'days').calendar();     


moment().format();                        // 2021-02-21T00:43:34-08:00
```

Try:
`moment().subtract(6, 'days').format()`

Comment: Is there a way to get the timestamp from this? Instead of it outputting the date string?

Comment: what do you mean by timestamp and not "data string"? using `moment.format()` it returns an ISO string, and you can get that into a JS date by doing `new Date(moment.format())` if you wanted to use the regular JS Date API after using moment to go back a certain interval of time

Comment: I need the timestamp and not the text string 'Last Monday at 12:17 AM', is there a way to do .calendar().timestamp? I cant find it in the moment docs. I tried also wrapping your answer in new Date(moment().subtract(10, 'days').calendar()) but its giving an error that its not a valid date

Comment: `new Date(moment().subtract(10, 'days').calendar().format())` should work. Check out the Date API and the Moment API websites for more clarification on what you're looking for

Comment: Im getting an error that format() isnt a function

Comment: Try removing the `calendar` part of it

Answer (score 0):

Handling date objects in javascript is bit tricky compared to other general purpose languages. However this could be achieved in Java script's `Date.parse(date)` method.
This method returns the timespan between the given date and 1970-01-01 in milliseconds.

So, I would do something like below to manipulate your scenario.

```
function getNewDate(originalDate, dateOffset){
    // converting original date to milliseconds
    var originalMS = Date.parse(originalDate);
    // calculating your date offest in milliseconds
    var offsetMS = dateOffset * 1000 * 3600 * 24;
    // apply the offset millisecons to original moment
    var newDateMS = originalMS + offsetMS;
    // Convert it back to new date object and return it
    return new Date(newDateMS);
}
```

You need to pass a date object and desired timespan in days as parameters to this function.
So you would call it as follows

```
var originalDate = new Date();

// To get new date after 2 weeks for the given original date
getNewDate(originalDate, 14)

// To get new date before 2 weeks for the given original date
getNewDate(originalDate, -14)
```

I hope this would answer you problem.